# Making variations of a cyclic modified loop walk cycle

Tags: animation, modifiers

I am wondering how I could make a walk cycle with variations after using a cyclic modifier to repeat the cycle infinitely.

My cycle runs for 30 frames for a cycle which then repeats. However, I'd love to alternate it so that the hand and body moves slightly different with each time it loops. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Would I have to just copy all the frames, duplicate and shift them to say frame 60 for a new cycle and edit them that way ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

- Duplicate the whole pose and make the changes you want all along the timeline.
- Create one cycle for the desired bones, select these bones only and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Make Cyclic*, only these bones will repeat the actions, you can keyframe the others the way you want (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Clear Cyclic* to disable, the *Cycles* modifier is visible in the *Graph Editor*).
- Manage the actions in the NLA (*Nonlinear Animation* window): Create the walk cycle, push down into the NLA, create a new action for the other bones, push down in the NLA as well, the new action will play over the walk cycle strip. You can even make some variations on the walk cycle itself with the right settings (in the N panel of the NLA choose *Blending > Combine*).